# How do I apply more padding to my view in vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to pad the content of my view by using the "px-5" class on the container in the view. But somehow I cant seem to pad the content as much as I want. What Im looking for is padding equivalent to the one on this screenshot of firebase:

[image: fantasy pic]

My App.Vue looks like this:

```
  <v-content>
      <div class="page-wrapper">
        <page-header></page-header>
          <router-view/>
      </div>        
  </v-content>
```

In the view:

```
<template>
  <div id="pageTable">
    <v-container grid-list-xl fluid px-5 pt-1 mx-auto>
      <h2>Mina ordrar</h2>
      <v-layout row wrap>
     <v-flex xs12 md12 lg12>
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="orders"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
    </v-data-table>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
     </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

Any ideas What im doing wrong?

Padding on my site:

[image: My site]

Comment: Check the [grid example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid#examples). You are looking for `justify-center`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `mx-auto` to keep the content centered then just set a `max-width` on the inner container.

A better suggestion building on the comment by @ljubadr - you can use `justify-center` on the wrapper - then use grid columns to set width dependent on breakpoints for example `sm-12 md-8` will fill 2/3 of the available space at the medium breakpoint and above, but on smaller screens will fill up all available space.

Answer (score 0):

If you use stylus loaders, you can override the `$spacer` variable before importing the styling. By default it is set to 16 pixels. Overriding this variable will recalculate the spacing of every element, which will keep a consistent spacing in your app.

If you want to accomplish something else entirely, you may be able to override the `$spacer-x`, `$spacer-y` or `$spacers` variables. Their defaults are as follows:

```
$spacer := 16px
$spacer-x := $spacer
$spacer-y := $spacer
$spacers := {
  zero: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  one: {
    x: ($spacer-x * .25),
    y: ($spacer-y * .25)
  },
  two: {
    x: ($spacer-x * .5),
    y: ($spacer-y * .5)
  },
  three: {
    x: $spacer-x,
    y: $spacer-y
  },
  four: {
    x: ($spacer-x * 1.5),
    y: ($spacer-y * 1.5)
  },
  five: {
    x: ($spacer-x * 3),
    y: ($spacer-y * 3)
  }
}
```

<sup>([source](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_variables.styl#L57))</sup>

If changing the overall margins of vuetify components is not what you are after, you may just want to define your own utility classes that go beyond m-5/p-5.